# how can i download the images with no extension on linux

Tags: python, linux, wget

In my python script i am getting the links of the images from the webpage. But few of the images links are like this

`image.php?u=155594&dateline=1182409179`

The terminal says like this

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4159 (4.1K) [image/png]
```

But image gets saved like `image.php?blabla`

is there any to save it in proper format with extension

Comment: Is there a content-disposition header in the response header? Auto renaming is based on the last token in the path, or the content-disposition. Other than that, you have to implement something yourself.

Comment: If you are using wget, you can use the -O option to specify the filename to save to.

Comment: @nhahtdh how can i mention content disposition. cna you give me some idea , how can i do that manually

Comment: @user19140477031: It depends on the server's response. If you are lucky, the server will send Content-disposition header, which you can ask wget to rename the file to it. There should be a switch for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using wget, you need to use the `-O` option to specify output file. For example:

```
wget -O img.png http://example.com/image.php?foo=bar
```

Here's a little python script for when you don't know the type:

```
import os
import urllib2
import sys
d = urllib2.urlopen(sys.argv[0])
o = open('image.%s' % d.info().gettype(), 'w')
o.write(d.read())
```

Comment: I am scrapping the images from the webpage in python so i don't know what extension will be for the images. Is there any way to autorename them. they are in 1000s